# How to use commands conveyor in Goland powershell terminal?

Tags: go, pipeline, goland

I have written two simple applications on Golang. The first app **fetch.go** displays html content of the main page by incoming links in arguments. The second app **findlinks1.go** find all href links in html tree. Here's the snippets:

```golang
func main() {
   for _, url := range os.Args[1:] {
      resp, err := http.Get(url)
      if err != nil {
         fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "fetch: %v\n", err)
         os.Exit(1)
      }
      b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
      resp.Body.Close()
      if err != nil {
         fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "fetch: reading %s: %v\n", url, err)
         os.Exit(1)
      }
      fmt.Printf("%s", b)
   }
}
```

```golang
func main() {
   doc, err := html.Parse(os.Stdin)
   if err != nil {
      fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "findlinks1: %v\n", err)
   }
   for _, link := range visit(nil, doc) {
      fmt.Println(link)
   }
   //it doesn't matter what the visit function does
}
```

I want to redirect the output of the 1st program to the input of the 2nd program in powershell terminal in Goland development environment, but I can't.

I have tried to run these commands in terminal:

```
./fetch.go https://golang.org | ./findlinks1.go
```

I got an error:

> InvalidOperation: Cannot run a document in the middle of a pipeline

---

```
go run fetch.go https://golang.org | go run findlinks1.go
```

I didn't get an error, but nothing happened after running this

Comment: The first command: it is not supposed to run plain Go files, you should build and run your program like `go run` or `go build` + `./binary.exe`. What is the expected result in the second pipe? You just build and run two programs separately. I'd suggest to pass output to a file e.g. `go run main.go https://go.dev/ > index.html` then handle `index.html` file in the second program e.g. `go run main.go https://go.dev/ > index.html | go run main2.go`.